# Selection on single date fails, between dates works fine?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

in an application I am working on , I need to be able to select records from a single date, or a selection of records of that chosen date, plus x minus y days ( a range of dates)

this is the working, multiple dates sql:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Select_Scandagen]

@datvoor datetime,
@datna datetime,
@scanner varchar(30)
AS
BEGIN

select ScannerID,ScannedTime,ScannedCode from [dbo].[tblScannedItems]
WHERE ScannedTime BETWEEN @datvoor AND @datna and  ScannerID like @scanner;
```

this is the non-working single date sql:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Select_Scandag]

@datum datetime,
@scanner varchar(30)
AS
BEGIN

select ScannerID,ScannedTime,ScannedCode from [dbo].[tblScannedItems]
WHERE ScannedTime like @datum AND ScannerID like @scanner;
```

When I execute the second one in SSMS I get:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[sp_Select_Scandag]
    @datum = N'15/7/2016',
    @scanner = N'975001'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure sp_Select_Scandag, Line 2
Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime.
```

Any suggestions?

thx,
James

Comment: Can't use LIKE with dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sql sever throws `Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime.` because `N'15/7/2016'` is a language dependent date format. Use language independent date format

```
@datum = N'20160715'
```

You can check your locale settings with  `dbcc useroptions;` command.

And if you need to compare only date part of Datetime variables cast both to Date.

```
WHERE cast(ScannedTime as date) = cast(@datum as date) AND ...
```

Comment: OK, I see what you mean, but the parameters are passed from a C# call. This works fine for the BETWEEN sp , so it's probably me trying to execute the sql in SSMS giving a wrong dateformat. I get no results back in the C# program running the stored procedure.

Comment: OK, adding the cast did the trick. Still can't figure out why this is not a problem in the other query. But hey, it works! Thanks!

Comment: It can be the problem if you'll pass `@datvoor = @datna` at the first case. Most probably `ScannedTime` has non zero time part. It fits between two different days start (zero time) but never matches single day start exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `like`, you'll need to use `=` when comparing a `datetime` field:

`ScannedTime = @datum`

Comment: @user3005015 but does it give the same error? Does it error at all? Also, if you use LIKE without wildcards it will operate as =, but still can't implicitly convert date to character type.